# Fragment cannot find variable from other Fragment

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I have 2 Android.Support.V4.App.Fragments

In the first Framgent I use this code:

```
AgentSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
AgentSpinner.Adapter = AgentSpinnerAdapter;

foreach (string[] str in NamesArray)
{
    string AgentId = str[0];
    string Owner = str[1];
    string Exchange = str[2];
    string Remark = str[3];

    AgentSpinnerAdapter.Add("Agent " + AgentId + " - " + Owner + " - " + Remark);
}
```

In the second Fragment I call this line:

```
dbValue = Fragment1.AgentSpinnerAdapter.GetItem(0);
```

But it says that AgentSpinnerAdapter is a nullreference, which is weird, because it get's filled. I have set the AgentSpinnerAdapter to `Public static`. Also in my MainActivity I first create Fragment1 and then Fragment2 like this:

```
Fragment1 = Fragment1.NewInstance();            
Fragment2 = Fragment2.NewInstance();
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here is the full Fragment1.cs method

```
public void LoadAgentSpinner()
{
    string json = "";

    try
    {
        string html = string.Empty;
        string url = "https://www.efy.nl/app/getagents.php";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        IgnoreBadCertificates();
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            NameValueCollection fields = new NameValueCollection();
            fields.Add("error", ex1.GetBaseException().ToString());
            string url = "https://www.mywebsite.com";
            IgnoreBadCertificates();
            byte[] respBytes = client.UploadValues(url, fields);
            string resp = client.Encoding.GetString(respBytes);

            SelectedQuantity.Text = "";
            SelectedLimit.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            string exFullName = (ex2.GetType().FullName);
            string ExceptionString = (ex2.GetBaseException().ToString());
        }
    }

    //Parse json content
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

    //Create Array from everything inside Node:"Coins"
    var agentPropery = jObject["Agents"] as JArray;

    //Create List to save Coin Data
    agentList = new List<agent>();

    //Find every value in Array: coinPropery
    foreach (var property in agentPropery)
    {
        //Convert every value in Array to string
        var propertyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<agent>>(property.ToString());

        //Add all strings to List
        agentList.AddRange(propertyList);
    }

    //Get all the values from Name, and convert it to an Array
    string[][] NamesArray = agentList.OrderBy(i => i.AgentId)
        .Select(i => new string[] { i.AgentId.ToString(), i.Owner, i.Exchange, i.Remark })
        .Distinct()
        .ToArray();


    AgentSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
    AgentSpinner.Adapter = AgentSpinnerAdapter;

    foreach (string[] str in NamesArray)
    {
        string AgentId = str[0];
        string Owner = str[1];
        string Exchange = str[2];
        string Remark = str[3];

        AgentSpinnerAdapter.Add("Agent " + AgentId + " - " + Owner + " - " + Remark);  // format your string here
    }

    if(MainActivity.db.CheckExistTableSettings("Default Agent") == true)
    {
        string Value = MainActivity.db.SelectValueFromTableSettings("Default Agent");
        int spinnerPosition = AgentSpinnerAdapter.GetPosition(Value);
        AgentSpinner.SetSelection(spinnerPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        AgentSpinner.SetSelection(0);
    }            
}
```

Comment: share `add()` method.

Comment: What do you mean with "share"?

Comment: means add code of `AgentSpinnerAdapter.Add("Agent " + AgentId + " - " + Owner + " - " + Remark);` method in above code.

Comment: I have added the right method to the question now. The method where I fill the AgentSpinner

Comment: is Fragment1 a static fragment class? because you're referencing it as if it is. But you need to access it from within the fragmentmanager.

Comment: I have declared the classes like instances. How can I access the framgent within the fragmentmanager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a few of my applications it's necessary to access the other fragments from my main Activity, so we do the following:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Fragment> FragmentList { get; set; }
    private Fragment currentFragment = null;
    private BottomNavigationView navigation;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout_mainactivity);

        // create our fragments and initialise them early.
        if (FragmentList == null)
        {
            FragmentList = new Dictionary<string, Fragment>
            {
                { "main", MainFragment.NewInstance() },
                { "bugreport", BugReportFragment.NewInstance() },
                { "settings", SettingsFragment.NewInstance() }
            };
        }

        navigation = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottom_nav);
        navigation.SetOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigation.SelectedItemId = Resource.Id.navigation_main;
    }

     public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        if (!popAction)
        {
            navigationResourceStack.Push(item.ItemId);
        }

        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.navigation_main:
                currentFragment = FragmentList["main"];
                break;
            case Resource.Id.navigation_settings:
                currentFragment = FragmentList["settings"];
                break;
            case Resource.Id.navigation_bugreport:
                currentFragment = FragmentList["bugreport"];
                break;
        }

        if (currentFragment == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.frame_content, currentFragment).Commit();
            return true;
        }
    }   
}
```

What this means is you could do something like MainActivity.FragmentList["main"] and then call any public method on the actual initialized class because a pointer to it is stored within the dictionary.

Comment: And how can I call a variable from a different fragment then?

Comment: To be honest, this wasn't really the awnser I hoped for. I have my own system in using fragments, which is based on the same thing. I just need to know how to access the variables from different classes

Comment: I showed you in the bottom part of the answer above how you can access the initialised instance of your other fragment through the FragmentList dictionary that you should create as part of your main activity.